# Toshiba C75D B7202 Windows 10 disable laptop trackpad and mouse

Tags: laptop, windows-10, mouse, touchpad

My fiancee and I just got a new Toshiba laptop, but whenever she uses the keyboard while on the Internet - any graze of the touchpad, or mouse buttons wreaks havoc on the Firefox and Waterfox browsers; i.e., changing of screen zoom; activation of a radio button within a website that wasn't intended, etc.

Toshiba refers to the usual mouse changes in Settings, which, affects Synaptics Pointing Device and the driver, making the USB mouse useless.

It used to be FN and F9 depressed together, to kill the trackpad and mouse on previous Windows iterations, while keeping the USB/wireless mouse working.

Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways you can do it.

In control panel under mouse, there should be a setting which allows you to disable the touchpad and buttons when a USB device is plugged in.

Or you could disable it through the device manager (my preference)

Or if you know what you're doing, you might be able to disable it in the BIOS